# Getting wifi router type from wifi not yet connected

Tags: android, api, wifi

Is there any way to get what kind of wifis are available near me? (whether it is a hotspot or normal router-oriented wifi) I'm trying to implement it via android.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**. The only way to recognize the kind of WiFi is by identifying the `SSID`. Such low level details of the network cannot be accessed using programming languages such as Java or Kotlin.

Although there is a `NetworkInterface` class, but it has no methods to read WiFi related information like `SSID` or `MAC` address.